# Building LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

Please help me to build a LINQ query.
I have a list `List<SingleEntryReportCardModel> singleEntryReportCardModel` which contains `EmployeeList` internally.
I want to have all such single  entry reports which matches to the employee name as input.
I have tried doing this

```
 singleEntryReportCardModel = 
 singleEntryReportCardModel
 .Where(x => x.EmployeeList.Select(y => y.EmployeeName.Contains(Name)))
 .ToList<SingleEntryReportCardModel>();
```

but throws me a type casting error

This is how it looks like:

```
public class SingleEntryReportCardModel
{
    public GoalReportCard GoalReportCard { get; set; }
    public GoalTemplateModel GoalTemplate { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeInfoModel> EmployeeList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more information? Specifically what your `SingleEntryReportCardModel` looks like?  We have no idea of properties or types on this object.

Comment: Getting compile time error ---  Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<Logic.Models.SingleEntryReportCardModel,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This LINQ will extract all the elements on which the Employee List contains at least one employee that contains the `Name`:

```
var result = singleEntryReportCardModel
    .Where(x => x
        .EmployeeList
        .Any(y => y.EmployeeName.Contains(Name)) //at least one employee contains the name
    )
    .ToList();  //obtain the list
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but the following line looks wrong:

```
.Where(x => x.EmployeeList.Select(y => y.EmployeeName.Contains(Name)))
```

The result of your `Select` will be an `IEnumerable<bool>`. I don't think that's even a valid argument to `Where`, but I might be wrong. It doesn't make sense to me to say "I want all elements where some collection of `bool`s".

Perhaps you want this:

```
.Where(x => x.EmployeeList.Any(y => y.EmployeeName.Contains(Name)))
```

Also, once you get it working, you should be able to remove the generic type argument from your call to `ToList`:

```
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

variant for query syntax

```
var res = (from x in singleEntryReportCardModel
          where x.EmployeeList.Any(y=>y.EmployeeName.Contains(Name))
          select x).ToList();
```